# Resizing a Matrix by summing the elements

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array of size 4x4:

```py
      1 1 1 1
A =   1 1 1 1
      1 1 1 1
      1 1 1 1
```

I want to reshape the above matrix into blocks of 2x2 shaped matrices such that the entries in this new matrix are the sums of the four quadrants of the 4x4 matrix.

```py
B = 4 4
    4 4
```

I am wondering if there is a simple way to do this in NumPy. `numpy.reshape()` does not allow for the data to be aggregated, so I am wondering if this would be something I need to do in an iteration.

Comment: Just do: `arr.reshape((2, 4, 2)).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: While this works, it's not what I need. I need to be able to add the four quadrants up as opposed to the column elements.

Comment: What do you mean by "add the four quadrants up"? Anyway does the duplicated link answers your question?

Comment: You can imagine the 4x4 matrix being made up of 4 2x2 matricies, which is essentially dividing the 4x4 matrix into 4 quadrants.